# Error: The application has already been subscribed to by another user for this company

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am locally testing an app that integrates with Quickbooks IPP. I had connected to a demo account provided by Quickbooks developer program when I signed up but it didn't have enough data so I created my own demo account with a copy of a bunch of good data. I then cleared out the tokens and stuff in my app stored from the other demo account so I could start over. The problem is, now when I try to connect my app to this new qb account (using a different login to Quickbooks), I just keep getting this error:

```
Oops! An error has occurred. 
Please close this window and try again. 

Error Code: invalid_database 
Message: The application has already been subscribed to by another user for this company
```

I don't see how anyone could have connected to this local app before, but just in case, I went to the "Manage My Apps" screen and the only thing I see there is "QuickBooks Online".

---

It is probably not related, but I'm also getting a javascript error message after clicking "Authorize" in the Intuit popup.

```
Line: 3
Error: Unexpected call to method or property access.
```

When I attempt to debug the javascript it is code in jQuery but seems to stem from the "notifyDoubleClickOfSalesActivity" function in the "Intuit.DFA.min.js" file.

---

What can I do at this point? I know my code is good because I was able to connect the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to you developer account and disconnect all connected connections. This should clear up the issue.

If not, please submit a support ticket through appcenter.intuit.com.

Comment: I couldn't find any way to disconnect the app from the end-user side, but "Disconnect All" Test Connections from the developer-side cleared it up, thanks!
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Developer/AppManage/xyz

Comment: You should be storing access tokens and realmids, so you can call the API to disconnect any of them as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a valid access token/connection for a particular company, another user from the same company cannot again authorize access. That is the error you see. If you go into your account on appcenter you can disconnect that IA connection, so you are able to re-create it with another user. Your code can also call the disconnect API to disconnect it, and lastly you can login as the end user and go to your account and disconnect the app.

Jarred